# subgroups of $\prod_p C_p$

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Consider the group $G:=\prod_p C_p$ where the product is taken over all primes, endowed with the product topology.

I'm trying to classify the compact subgroups of $G$. Is there any subgroups of $G$ besides direct products of finite groups?

Comment: It could be easier to consider the Pontryagin dual question: whether for any subgroup of $\bigoplus_pC_p$, the quotient is a direct sum of finite groups.

Comment: The map of $\mathbb Z$ into $C_p$ for each $p$ gives a diagonal imbedding of $\mathbb Z$ into the product of $C_p$. The image is a dense subgroup. Do you ask for all compact groups or for "non-standard" subgroups?

Comment: @Venkataramana But that subgroup is not compact?

Comment: no, that group is dense

Comment: Yes only compact subgroups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G$ be your group and $C$ a compact subgroup. Both $G$ and $C$ are profinite groups. The Sylow subgroups of $G$ are $C_p$ and any Sylow subgroup of $C$ is contained in a Sylow subgroup of $G$. Therefore, it is either trivial or $C_p$. Since $G$ is abelian so is $C$ and thus, $C$ is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups.

Comment: OMG so easy! Especially compared to mine...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე thinking about it there is even a simpler argument. $G$ is a cyclic group (in the profinite sense). Take a generator $x$ then every closed subgroup is generated by a power of $x$ and its order divides the order of the original group. (Orders and powers here are product of powers of primes, possibly infinite powers and infinite number of primes.)

Comment: Dear@YiftachBarnea I want to know why you say "it is either trivial or $C_p$", thanks!

Comment: $C_p$ is a group of prime order it subgroups are either trivial or the group itself. (Their order has to divide the $p$.)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like all compact subgroups are indeed of the form $\prod_{p\in S}C_p$ for some subset $S$ of primes.

As mentioned in the comment, via Pontryagin duality this is equivalent to the following statement: any quotient of $\bigoplus_pC_p$ is of the form $\bigoplus_{p\in S}C_p$.

For an element $a=(a_p)_p$ of $\bigoplus_pC_p$ define its *support* $\operatorname{supp}(a):=\{p\mid a_p\ne0\}$; this is a finite set of primes. Clearly any $a$ is a generator of the subgroup $\bigoplus_{p\in\operatorname{supp}(a)}C_p\cong C_{\prod_{p\in\operatorname{supp}(a)}p}$.

Let now the quotient in question be by some subgroup $H<\bigoplus_pC_p$. For an element $h\in H$, the quotient map $\bigoplus_pC_p\twoheadrightarrow(\bigoplus_pC_p)/\langle h\rangle$, by the above, can be identified with the projection $\bigoplus_pC_p\twoheadrightarrow\bigoplus_{p\notin\operatorname{supp}(h)}C_p$.

It then follows (I believe) that the quotient $\bigoplus_pC_p\twoheadrightarrow(\bigoplus_pC_p)/H$ is isomorphic to the projection $\bigoplus_pC_p\twoheadrightarrow\bigoplus_{p\notin\bigcup_{h\in H}\operatorname{supp}(h)}C_p$.

Comment: I think you're right. Thank you for your help.